# Transitive set merging

Tags: algorithm, set

Is there a well-known algorithm, that given a collection of sets, would merge together every two sets that have at least one common element? So for example, given the following input:

```
A B C
B D
A E
F G H
I J
K F
L M N
E O
```

It would produce:

```
A B C D E O
F G H K
I J
L M N
```

I already have a working implementation, but it seems to be common enough that there has to be a name for what I am doing.

Comment: I think you can formulate this as finding connected components in a hypergraph. That gives a quadratic time algorithm, and I'm not sure whether this can be made linear.

Comment: I think this is called a [set consolidation](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Set_consolidation).  Alternatively, you can view it as finding the connected components in a graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can model this as a simple graph problem: Introduce a node for every distinct element. Introduce a node for every set. Connect every set to the elements it contains. You get an (undirected) bipartite graph, in which the connected components are the solution of your problem. You can use [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) to find the CCs.

The runtime should be linear (with hash tables, so only expected runtime unless your numbers are bounded).

I don't think it deserves a special name, it's just an application of well-known concepts.

Comment: +1 Excellent observation. I didn't think of making it into a bipartite graph.

Comment: @templatetypedef There are multiple ways to avoid the quadratic number of edges. Alternatively we could connect every set for every element it contains only to the next set that contains that element (basically producing a number of linked lists of sets that contain an element)

Comment: Thanks! It makes it much easier to think about it is as a bipartite graph. I was able to come up with a more efficient implementation thanks to your answer.

Comment: @sagi That only shows that you asked the wrong question ;) Glad I could help